# Protrocol in Flash Player 10.x is not compatible with Flash Player 11.x when using video stream multicast

Tags: flash, rtmfp

I have a swc plugin embedded in my product to stream live video to a group of recipients.

The plugin uses the NetStream, NetGroup, and NetConnection objects, the server I use to handle the RTMFP session is Influxis.

One client creates a group as a publisher, and stream a live video. His Camera is enabled and I can see the video on the screen as well.
The others connect to his group and play the video.
Peer assisted Networking is enabled for both the publisher and the recipients.

The plugin worked well in all 10.x versions (10.1/10.2/10.3)

However, when upgrading to flash player 11.x, it stopped working.

- 11.x to 11.x isn't working.
- 10.x with 11.x isn't working.

Only 10.x to 10.x is working.

The server I use to handle the RTMFP protocol is Influxis.com
I sent them the same question as well.

The weirdest fact is that I'm using flash builder 4.6 with 4.6 SDK, which is aimed for flash player 11.1, and it is only working with 10.x flash players.

Comment: To be more clear:
10.x with 10.x is working.
11.x with 10.x is not working.
11.x with 11.x is not working.

Thanks again,

Comment: Up there you can see what happens when you fall asleep trying to debug somthing:)

Comment: We are using the rtmfp protocol to open a group connection, using a
NetGroup, where each client streams each own video and listen to
others.

I've retried streaming between a flash player 10.3 and 11.1, it didn't work. 
This involved opening 2 netgroup on each client, where one
publishes and one plays the other.

Example:
Client 1 publishes stream "a" and plays "b" using flash player 10.3

Client 2 publishes stream "b" and plays "a" using flash player 11.1

Moreover, the plugin crashes on the client machines.

Comment: it looks like the NetConnection connects, the group is created, attached to the video object, but the plugin in one of the sides crash while trying to connect to the group and play\publish the video

Comment: one more detail:

i'm not sure if it related, but the video dimensions we're using is 80 width and 60 height

Comment: The same code runs perfectly on 10.x versions 10.2,10.3 and 10.1 if I'm not mistaken.

Something has changed in 11.1 as it always crashes. The flash executable itself crashes, i get no nice flash exception.

When I comment out the NetGroup object and the calls to it, preventing from the streams to connect, it does not crash.

I've also started from scratch, copying the code from tutorials and it crashes.

I use win7 to run flash player 11.1 and XP SP2 to run flash player 10.3