# My flex application cannot play a RTMFP stream. NetStream.Play.Failed error

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, flash, rtmfp

Years ago, I created a SWF application that enabled users to perform online video chat. It used simple SMTFP publish/play method to stream video. Now a few years passed and i am trying to create a backward compatible SWF application.

My problem status:

- New version fails to play the streams that are published from the old swf. It
  connects to server and to the publisher, but it cannot play and gives
  the `NetStream.Play.Failed` error.
- New version plays the streams that are published from its own version.
- Online players like in this
  [guide](http://myprojectguide.org/p/flash-videoio/9.html) can play my new version, but they are unable to play
  streams from my old version.

I tried it with different SDKs (3.6, 4.1, 4.6) and they all fail to play the old swf streams.

I searched the web for the error and documents don't clear anything and they are just saying that it is a general error. There is [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242843/rtmfp-protrocol-in-flash-player-10-x-is-not-compatible-with-flash-player-11-x-wh) that could be related, but it has no answers.

Does anyone know the reason? or any suggestions?

Comment: Which server do you use? It will be interesting to investigate into the server logs.

Comment: @thomas I don't have a server myself. I use rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net which is the same used in the guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It seems like the flash player has changed RTMFP protocol in 11.1 version. There is not much documentation about it and as far as i can understand, I should either upgrade all the flash players or I should upgrade all of the old applications to flex 4 sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the same publication names are used in both applications? It is possible that you publish a stream with name "test1" for example and the player try to play the stream with name "test2".

Otherwise if you think that the names are correct you can try with [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/), it is our own open source server. It supports RTMFP, RTMP[E], HTTP and Websocket (also RTSP for testing only). Install it on your computer/server and check the log to see what's going on.

Comment: No I double checked. Thanks for the suggestion.